# How an event handler can raise itself automatically?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two buttons in my WPF form namely Play and Forward. Play button reads the text entered in the TextBox but cannot highlight the sentences. On the other hand the forward button can highlight one sentence of the text entered in the TextBox in each press.

I want the forward button event handler be raised automatically when it reads one sentence. In this case forward button can read one highlighted sentence and after that can highlight the second sentence and reads that and so on.

I don't know how to programmatically raise the forward button event handler by itself

```
private void btnForward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    highlightText();
    synth.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
    synth.SpeakAsync(textArea.SelectedText);
    //here it should be raised automatically again
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to raise the `Click` event again when you haven't actually clicked again. But that aside, suppose it did work, what would the effect be? The second sentence would be *immediately* selected, and the `synth.SpeakAsyncCancelAll()` would cancel the first sentence. The whole point of `SpeakAsync` is that execution of your code continues *before* the speaking is done.

Comment: I think the second sentence wont be _immediately_ selected because `synth.SpeakAsync(textArea.SelectedText);` causes the event to wait till it reads the previously selected sentence.

Comment: No, it does not. Again, that's the whole point of the `...Async` functions: the `Speak` method waits. The `SpeakAsync` method does not wait. That's mentioned in the documentation, too. You can easily see that by adding a line like `MessageBox.Show("...");`, and checking whether you get a message box during the speaking, or afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that I was wrong. 
So what is your idea to how to do my job done (described in my question)?

Comment: I think the basic idea would have to be that you'd listen to the `SpeakCompleted` event, and when that happens, determine whether it is a result of your "Forward" button (this will require you to keep track of which button is "active"), see if there is a following sentence, and if so, select it and speak.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want the user to have to press the "Forward" button only once. After that, the program should automatically keep advancing the text selection, as it does the first time the button is pressed, and playing the speech synth for each newly selected piece of text.

If so, then I believe this *could* work:

```
private async void btnForward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btnForward.Enabled = false;
    while (true)
    {
        highlightText();

        // NOTE: use whatever expression correctly identifies the state after
        // you've called highlightText() when there's no more text to read.
        // Here I've assumed that the selection will simply be empty, but
        // if that's not right, presumably you have _some_ way to know that
        // you're at the end of the text.
        if (textArea.SelectedText == "")
        {
            break;
        }

        synth.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
        await Task.Run(() => synth.Speak(textArea.SelectedText));
    }
    btnForward.Enabled = true;
}
```

**<EDIT>**
I ran a little test, and it appears to be that the `SpeakAsyncCancelAll()` method does not interfere with an immediately subsequent call to the `Speak()` method. In addition, I found out that it *does* cancel synchronous speech operations (i.e. it will interrupt an in-progress call to `Speak()`). So the above should definitely work fine, and you can even add a separate button to cancel the operation, simply by setting a flag and then calling `SpeakAsyncCancelAll()` to interrupt the current speech operation.
**</EDIT>**

Long-term, a much better solution would be to implement a true `async`-supporting wrapper around the `SpeechSynthesizer` class. Unfortunately, as near as I can tell, the only built-in implementation for speech synthesis that supports `async`/`await` directly is a Windows Phone-only version of the `SpeechSynthesizer` class. But you should be able to write your own wrapper, using `TaskCompletionSource` along with handling of the various `SpeechSynthesizer` events to allow asynchronous methods that fit the `async`/`await` paradigm.

Note that in the above, I disable the button so that the event isn't raised again while it's handling the previous button press. You wouldn't want this code to have concurrent iterations, so I'm relying on the UI state to prevent re-entry here.

Finally note that the above doesn't provide any way for the user to interrupt the progress of the looping through the text selections. You didn't provide enough context in your original question to know how that would work, so I just left it out. But as I note above, you can interrupt a synchronous speech operation using the `SpeakAsyncCancelAll()` method, so this would be as simple as setting a flag as I mentioned above, calling the cancel method, and then in the loop above checking that flag to see if you need to break out early.

Comment: Basically I am writing a program that reads some text. It should also highlight each sentence that it is reading. The user should be able to move forward and backward. Forwarding will highlight and read the next sentence and backward does the reverse. 
[here](http://bdatech.org/what-technology/text-to-speech/) is an example of such a software.

Comment: My program can only read one sentence of a text on each press of play button but doesn't get going forward.